# How get auto number based on selected drop down list

Tags: php, regex, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm not good in English. I'm new newbie in PHP and YII2 too.

The picture below here. That my question.

How to get value from selected Drop Drown List for generate auto number code
and increment(+1) for new summit value.

After submit form will generate auto number code from selected drop down list.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

I try to learn from https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-autonumber, but too hard.

Answer (score 0):

your model

```
class MyModel extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $subCode1; // AA or BB
    public $subCode2; // 01, 02, 03, ...

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['subCode1', 'subCode2'], 'safe'],
            [['number'] , 'autonumber', 'digit'=>4, 'format'=>function(){
                return $this->subCode1 . $this->subCode2 . '?';
            }]
        ];
    }
}
```